# Can partial views affect markup outside themselves?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

Is it possible for Razor partials to communicate/affect each other or the layout?  And is it possible for them to affect markup outside -- and especially "above" -- themselves?

One thing I like about controls in Webforms is that they can "communicate" with the master page or with each other.

For instance, if a user control needs some special CSS, you can do something like this:

```
Page.Head.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<style>[something here]</style>"));
```

That would inject a STYLE block into the HEAD tag of the page.  Hence, the user control can talk "outside" itself and -- in this case -- "above" itself.  Even if the user control is at the bottom of the page, it can "reach up" the page and affect other controls and markup.

Now, with MVC, say I have a partial.  That partial needs custom CSS.  How does it speak to the layout template to tell it to put CSS in the HEAD tag?  Additionally, say this partial is used twice -- how do you make sure it only does this once?

I have a section for HeadTagContent (a vestigial ContentPlaceHolder from when the app was in Webforms), but even if I use this in the partial, when the partial renders we're "below" the section, so it doesn't do anything.

I do have a ViewModel class. I could create a property for "CustomCss" and set/append this from the partial (yes, this might be bad form...) and then write it into the HEAD tag from the layout. However, again, by the time my partial does this the layout has already rendered which means we're "below" the HEAD tag.

What am I not understanding, philosophically, here?  While my CSS issue is my acute problem, I'm trying to grok the larger point/architecture.

Answer (score 1):

In razor, the equivalent of what you are looking for is called [sections](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx) <-- good guide.

In your `_Layout.cshtml` file you put code like this:

```
@RenderSection("Scripts", false) // true = section required
                                 //false = section optional
```

and

```
@RenderBody()
```

Then in your views you put code like this

```
@section Scripts
{
   <!--
       razor and html markup placed here gets rendered in the "Scripts"
       section in _Layout.cshtml
    -->
}
<!-- code here goes in RenderBody()-->
```

Comment: Sections are not functionally equivalent. Specifically, you cannot define a section in a partial view and expect it to render in the layout of the "parent" view. This only works if the partial view has its own layout.

Comment: Okay, but by the time my partial executes, we're already "below" the "RenderSection" line.  Will this still work?  (It's not, in my code, though I concede I may be doing something wrong.)

Comment: Yes, what @Jens explains above is my problem. The section defined in the partial is not reaching all the back back up into the layout.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between WebForms and MVC Views is that WebForms creates an object tree, consisting of various controls and other parts. Once this tree has been created, the page is rendered by recursively asking the controls to render themselves. Because this happens very late, you can reference back to parts of the page that came before your control was inserted, because the page hasn't rendered yet.

MVC Razor Views on the other hand, are executed in a single pass. The ViewEngine is instantiated, receives the view, the viewdata and (potentially) the model and starts executing code (or outputting HTML) from top to bottom. Loading a layout and rendering sections into it is not even required, but completely optional. And since that process is single-pass, from top to bottom, you cannot do back-references, since that part has already been completed and possibly even been sent to the browser.

Comment: This makes sense.  So, given the architecture you described, what is the solution for the problem I presented (partials requiring custom CSS)?

Comment: The logic of whether to include the CSS must live in the view that is calling the partial. If it is conditional, you can decide at the very beginning of the view whether you need the partial and remember that in a local boolean. Or you could do something a little more complicated with a HtmlHelper function.

Comment: Well, or you could not conditionally load CSS at all. Just include it with your global (hopefully) minimized CSS and scope the CSS selectors so that it only applies to the partial view contents.

Comment: What I don't love, though, is separating the template code in the partial from the CSS it needs. I like the idea of both those things being the same file, so it's portable.